# How does Wall of Force interact with objects?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wall

*Wall of Force* discusses what happens when it goes through a creature's space:

> If the wall cuts through a creature’s space when it appears, the
> creature is pushed to one side of the wall (your choice which side).

...and I assume similar logic can be applied to small/medium sized objects such as chairs that can be moved.

But what about objects that are not a creature, or a single creature, and aren't particularly mobile?

For example:

a)  An enemy is hanging from a rope.  Mage casts a horizontal *Wall of Force* that "cuts" through the rope.

b)  A Chain Devil has grappled the fighter from 10' away with its **Chain** attack that has 10' reach.  Mage casts *Wall of Force* between them as part of a hemisphere, hoping to cut the chain and trap the devil.

If the object was a stone wall, I think most would agree that the stone wall stops the Wall of Force as the panels wouldn't be contiguous or the sphere wouldn't be able to expand in a direct line from its point of origin.

Does something as thing as a rope or chain have a similar effect?

Could the area of a Wall of Force be greatly reduced just by having streamers hanging from the ceiling, or standing in a forest with a bunch of tall trees?

Answer (score 4):

### You'll have to ask your DM

The rules for *wall of force* don't specify what happens if it bisects an object; only how it influences creatures. When the rules on something aren't clear, it is up to the DM how to adjudicate the situation.

After all, the [foundational rule for D&D](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#HowtoPlay) is as follows:

> 1. The DM describes the environment.
> 2. The players describe what they want to do.
> 3. The DM narrates the results of the adventurers’ actions.

If a player describes an action that doesn't have established rules (in this case, casting *wall of force* to bisect an object), it is up to the DM to narrate the results.

### Past editions

One thing of note is that in past editions, the spell would fail if an object were in the way. Here is the relevant line from AD&D 2e:

> The wall of force must be continuous and unbroken when formed; if its surface is broken by any object or creature, the spell fails

...and from 3.xe:

> If [the wall's] surface is broken by any object or creature, the spell fails.

The 5e version of the spell, however, lacks this clause. That being said, a DM could rule this way, in which case the streamer technique could definitely work.

Comment: I *am* the DM.  :-)

I'm looking for more specific responses though.  Eg. "there's nothing RAW, but here are some relevant references from past editions or other answers or Crawford tweets"

Comment: @M.Vienneau Okay; I'll add some more context, but just so you know; idea generation stuff is out-of-scope for this site. I try to avoid making recommendations that aren't back by experience or evidence. That being said, I can add some stuff.

Comment: To be fair, I was also checking if there was anything obvious that I missed, because the question seems like one that would come up.  So you did reassure me that I wasn't just thinking strangely about a question with an obvious answer.